# How to increase document library limit?

Tags: list, document-library, list-view

I have got 4369 documents and i want to add them all. Is there a way to add them to the site? Is it possible to increase limit or to compress the files or any other solution?

Answer (score 3):

Document library can contain 30000000 documents. Mentioned limit of 5000 is related to List View Treshold only. It means that single query can process/display up to 5000 items/documents at once. In case of administrators, this limit is 20000 items/documents.

Please take a look at this table [List and Library limits](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#ListLibrary) - it specify all limits.

As mentioned before, using Explorer View can be a way to upload all documents at once.

Comment: just a note... in my o365 tenant explorer view does not work on libraries wit mire than 5000 docs. may not be pertinent to the question, but thought i'd mention it

Answer (score 1):

The default limit in SharePoint 2013 document library is 5000. You can use explorer view to bulk upload the documents.